# concatenate two pandas dataframes with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, called data and data1 (which I extracted both from an unestructured excel file).

data is a one row dataframe.
data1 is a multiple row dataframe (it will vary depending on the original excel file).

What I want to achieve is to concatenate both, but the values from data repeat for each row in data1. resulting like this:

| data | data | data | data1 | data1 | data1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | asda | dsad | dsass |
| One | Two | Three | dsad | dasda | dasds |
| One | Two | Three | asda | asdsss | dsass |
| One | Two | Three | adsa | dsad | asdds |

Is there an efficient way to do this? I've been doing it manually, but it is taking too long because there are like 1k+ files.

Best regards.

Comment: Would you be able to show what is the desired output that you are seeking?

Comment: I think it's simple. Just do ``new_df = df.merge(df2`` no need to explicitly mention how='cross'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'])
data = data.T
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['asda', 'dsad', 'adsa'],
                        "col2": ['dsad', 'dasda', 'asdsss'],
                        "col3": ['dsass', 'dasds', 'asdds']})
data.merge(data1, how = 'cross')
```

which should give:

```py
    0   1   2       col1    col2    col3
0   One Two Three   asda    dsad    dsass
1   One Two Three   dsad    dasda   dasds
2   One Two Three   adsa    asdsss  asdds
```

It's then kind of down to you how you want to deal with your column names. You cannot have more than one column with the same name so `data` can't be reused. You can either directly rename them after `data.merge(...)` (which is probably cleaner) or use

```py
data.merge(data1, how = 'cross', suffixes = ("_data", "data1"))
```

but this will only have an effect if the column names in the two dataframes match. E.g.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'])
data = data.T
data.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['asda', 'dsad', 'adsa'],
                        "col2": ['dsad', 'dasda', 'asdsss'],
                        "col3": ['dsass', 'dasds', 'asdds']})

data.merge(data1, how = 'cross', suffixes = ("_data", "_data1"))
```

which gives

```
   col1_data    col2_data   col3_data   col1_data1  col2_data1  col3_data1
0     One           Two        Three       asda        dsad       dsass
1     One           Two        Three       dsad        dasda      dasds
2     One           Two        Three       adsa        asdsss     asdds
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick with this answer, which worked perfectly. 
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
pd.concat([data.reindex(data.index.repeat(len(data1))).reset_index(drop=True), 
           data1], 
          axis=1, 
          ignore_index=True)
```

Details:

- Repeat the one row index of data for the number of rows in data1.
- Reindex data to expand the size the number of rows in data and drop
  repeated index.
- Concatenate data with data1 using axis=1.

#### Timing Test

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.testing as pt

data = pd.DataFrame(data = [['One', 'Two', 'Three']], columns=['a','b','c'])

data1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['asda', 'dsad', 'adsa'],
                        "col2": ['dsad', 'dasda', 'asdsss'],
                        "col3": ['dsass', 'dasds', 'asdds']})

def reindex_repeat(data1):
    return pd.concat([data.reindex(data.index.repeat(len(data1))).reset_index(drop=True), 
           data1], 
          axis=1)

def merge_cross(data1):
    return data.merge(data1, how = 'cross')

pt.assert_frame_equal(merge_cross(data1), reindex_repeat(data1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 5, 10, 30, 50, 100, 300, 500, 700, 1000],
    columns='reindex_repeat merge_cross'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([data1]*i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit.timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

res.groupby(res.columns.str[4:-1], axis=1).plot(loglog=False, ax=ax);
```

###### Chart Output:

[image]